# How to replace "xxxxxx@example.com" as administrator of Bitnami GitLab image on AWS?

Tags: gitlab, bitnami

After installing the GitLab AMI image, is there a quick hack for the back-end database to replace "@example.com" references to my own?

There is no way to fix this through the normal UI since it needs email confirmation.

Instructions are scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a non-issue if email is properly configured on the box.

`apt-get install postfix`